# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I am making a ticket command but got this error:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.
It is only happening in this command nothing else

Please help thank you

Here is my code

```
bot.on("message", async message =>{
    const args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ")
    if(message.author.bot) return
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return
    if(message.content.startsWith(`${PREFIX}openticket`)){
        const reason = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
        const role2 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role2 => role2.name == "@everyone");

   const channel =  message.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${message.author.username}`,  {
        permissionOverwrites: [
            {
              id: role2.id,
              deny: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
              deny: 'READ_MESSAGES',
              deny: 'SEND_MESSAGES'
            }, {
              id: message.author.id,
              allow: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
              allow: 'READ_MESSAGES',
              allow: 'SEND_MESSAGES'
            }
          ]

    })

        const embedcreated = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#f00202")
        .setDescription(`You ticket has been created ` + `#ticket-${message.author.username}` )
        .setTitle("Tickets")
        .setFooter(`Tickets System`)
        .setTimestamp()

        message.channel.send(embedcreated);

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#f00202")
        .addField(`Hey ${message.author.username}!`, ` Please wait until support arrives`)
        .addField(`Reason`, reason)
        .setTimestamp();
        channel.send(embed);
        channel.send(`${message.author}`)
}})
```

Comment: the only `addField` that could be empty is `reason` ... check if it is

Comment: oh ok I just deleted that part and it worked ty

Comment: so `reason` is empty, perhaps you need to check why